# Как открыть в браузере проект vue js?

Tags: linux, vue.js

Установил на vps (linux, centOS 6.5) vue js.

После выполнил запуск проекта:

> cd vueapp01
>
> npm run dev

После чего мне выдало:

> Your application is running here: http://localhost:8081

Но непонятно как открыть эту страницу? Сервер ведь vps...

IP сервера: (например) 256.125.568.22 , пробовал открыть по ссылке 256.125.568.22:8081 - отвечает: *Не удается получить доступ к сайту*

Comment: Может у Вас прокси какой-нибудь стоит и его настроить надо?

Comment: @Дмытрык никакого прокси нет..

Comment: а... скорее всего, в настройках вебпака, параметр `host` необходимо установить в значение `0.0.0.0`

Comment: @Дмытрык помогло, только вместо 0.0.0.0 прописал ip сервера. можете оформить это в ответ, отмечу как решение! спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для публикации лучше код собрать `npm run build` и скормить web-серверу . Например nginx

```
server {

    listen      80;
    server_name host.ex;

    root        /opt/vueproject/dist/;
    index       index.html;


    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

Для разработки очень удобно использовать проброс порта по ssh ([putty в картинках](https://putty.org.ru/articles/putty-ssh-tunnels.html)):

```
ssh host.ex -L 8081:127.1:8081
```

Обращаясь на свой `localhost` попадаете на `127.0.0.1` удалённый. Открывать разработку во вне не рекомендуется.